# sildeup,slidedown on hover with dropdownlist

Tags: jquery

I have a ul li tag, contain asp:dropdownlist (inside a div)

when the user is over the li ,the div with the dropdownlist is slideDown and when the user unhover the li ,the div is slideUp.

The problem happen when I try to choose value from the dropdownlist ,the div is slideup,so there isn't a option to choose values from this dropdownlist.

Why is this happen?(I am still on the li.hover!)

what are my options?

This is  HTML example :

```
  <ul><li id="l2"><img src=4.gif  />
<div id="popup6" class="popup_block">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dd" runat=server>
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>        
            </asp:DropDownList>
</div></li></ul>
```

This is the Jquery example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#l2").hover(function () {
            $('#popup6').stop(true, true).slideDown();

        }, function () {
            $('#popup6').stop(true, true).fadeOut(400, function () {
                return false;

            });


        });

    });
```

Thanking you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

$(function(){

$("select").mouseleave(function (event) { event.stopPropagation(); });

});

it will slove the problem:)